# Html5 video, works fine except in Safari where only audio plays

Tags: jquery, html, video-streaming, html5-video, h.264

I seem to be having a problem specifically with Safari where the video refuses to play and instead plays just the audio.

The code is pretty straightforward

```
  <video  id="bgvid" preload="auto">
                <source src="video.m4v" type="video/mp4" />
                <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm" />
                <source src="video.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
            </video>
```

The other strange thing is if I browse directly to the video, it plays fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with your CSS media query here:

```
@media only screen (max-device-width : 1024px) { 
    video#bgvid{display:none;}
    .mobile-vid {display:block !important; position:absolute;overflow:hidden;z-index: -1;} 
}
```

According to the [media query syntax guide on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries#Logical_operators), when you have multiple conditions for a rule, you need to join those conditions either with "and" or with a comma. "and" obviously means "and." A comma means "or." My guess is that the browsers are handling your syntax error differently. Chrome assumes you missed an "and" and Safari assumes you missed a comma. So the rule fires whenever you have a screen, regardless of the device width, and your video is `display:none`.

You can fix it by putting an "and" in like so:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
```

Comment: Awesome dude, worked like a charm, what a strange bug though.